# Access Value of a Control

Tags: ms-access, vba

On access, I have a navigation form (Stage) with a dropdown list (Modifiable84). How can I collect the value of these controls in each tabs (tabX, tabY ...) of my navigation form?

I've tried in a variable: `X_var = Modifiable84.Value` but I've got an error.

Comment: Please be explicit: are you using a tab control or a navigation control? Are you using subforms?

Comment: I've several form (Form1 Form2 Form3 Form4) and a navigation form (Stage) which contains 4 tabs that gives the form1, form2 ... And the dropdownlost (Modifiable84) is placed on the top next to these 4 tab. And in each vba of form1 form2... i would like to collect the value of the modifiable84.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refer to a control on a specific subform, you need to use the subform name. E.g. `X_var = Form1.Form.Modifiable84.Value` where `Form1` is the subform control name, not the form name.

Note that if you're using a navigation control, the form needs to be loaded.

Comment: I use this code: Promo_var = Menu.Stage.Modifiable84.Value  but i've an error: compilation error; variable undefined !

Comment: That doesn't look like the code I shared at all, for example, `.Form.` isn't in it

Comment: The good syntax for my situation was: X_var = Forms.Menu.Modifiable84.Value   Thanks